# Как выкачивать обновления json с веб-сайта на c#

Tags: c#, wpf, json

Привет всем, я относительно новичок в c#. Стоит задача читать json с веб-сайта.Это реализовано следующим образом:

```
        string url =   "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson";
        string json;
        using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
        {

            json = webclient.DownloadString(url);
        }
```

Но суть в том что сайт на котором находится json обновляется и добавляются новые элементы массива, и нужно в real-time сразу получать новые данные.
Буду очень благодарен на любую помощь)

Comment: Сервер отдает длину контента? Дату последнего изменения?

Answer (score 1):

Заведите таймер и скачивайте по нему.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ,но мне кажется это не решение проблемы, ведь данные могут появится как и через 5 сек,так и через через 30 сек, потавив таймер через 30 сек, я пропущу тот элемент который был добавлен через 5 секунд.И wpf приложение должен сразу вывести мне информацию о новом элементе,как то так

Comment: Нет никакого способа узнать что удаленный файл обновился иначе как заново его скачать.

Comment: Тем более что json формируется в момент обращения к скрипту.

Comment: @madmadik может этот сайт умеет оповещать о появлении новых данных у себя на сайте ?

Comment: @rawman да там есть такая функция,https://earthquake.usgs.gov/ens/,  но там нету api для разрабов

Comment: Там просто рассылка емайлов при землетрясении больше 6 баллов. Не поможет оно вам.

Answer (score 1):

Глянул на ответ от данного веб-сайта, и увидел следующие заголовки:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    accept,origin,authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Cache-Control   public, max-age=35
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  21304
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date    Sat, 27 Jan 2018 14:35:30 GMT
Expires Sat, 27 Jan 2018 14:36:05 GMT
Last-Modified   Sat, 27 Jan 2018 14:35:05 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security   max-age=31536000
Vary    Accept-Encoding
```

Тут можно увидеть самое важное, это длина контента (`Content-Length`), и дата (`Last-Modified`) изменения, а так же истечение времени жизни кэша. По данным заголовкам можно сделать так, что будем обновлять только то, что было обновлено, т.е. загружать отсутствующую длину, и уже на основе полученных данный как-то соединять их со старыми. Под руками нет ничего чем можно было бы показать пример реализации, но думаю вам будет достаточно и логической части.

P.S. Судя по всему, контент может меняться и в середине, что делает реализацию более сложной, но все же придется читать полный ответ, хотя можно было бы обойтись и без этого, знать бы какая часть была обновлена.